# T-SQL Chain of Views / Calculations

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, stored-procedures, view

Are these two tsql workflows equivalent or is the stored procedure better?
The tables are large and each 'step' is somewhat complicated with calculations and joins of multiple views.

I'm basically asking if it is important for the where clause to be at the end or beginning of a chain of views / calculations.

**Chain of 3 views where clause at the last step.**

- Step1View = Select  from Tables
- Step2View = select  from @Step1View
- Step3View = select  from @Step2View
- Select  from Step3View  where x=1 and y=2 and z = 3

**Single stored procedure containing all the steps with a where clause at the first step.**

- Stored Procedure:

  - @Step1View = Select  from Tables where x=1 and y=2 and z = 3
  - @Step2View = select  from @Step1View
  - @Step3View = select from @Step2View
  - Select  from @Step3View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested views are terrible for performance. See this [StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5491/95107) post, and this [RedGate](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/) post about this. And since you only tagged TSQL, I'm speaking from a SQL Server view only.

But to answer your question, yes, the placement of the where clause would change the performance for many reasons including:

- Limiting the numbers of rows which need to be returned thus reducing memory
- Reducing the number of rows which would have to be joined / filtered out later in your query, which reduces CPU and memory
- Limit the likelihood of increased I/O due to data not already being in memory

What you likely should look into is common table expressions and temporary tables. Since you stated the tables are large, you may also want to consider [creating indexes on your temporary tables](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/12/indexing-temp-tables/) which would increase performance over unmaterialized views.